# When addSubview and release not working properly in added view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4

I'm created Class and it's add to the current view with non arc project. After that i'm releasing it as this.

```
  TestViewController *tView=[[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
tView.view.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10,tView.view.frame.size.width , tView.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:tView.view];
[tView release];
```

I added button to the TestViewController and when pressed it just crash and view this message from console.

```
-[TestViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Anyone can explain the reason for that?

Comment: show your button add and buttonclick action code...

Comment: Adding the `tView.view` as subview will **not** retain the `TestViewController` instance. Since this instance is getting a message after being released, your app is crashing. Keep the `TestViewController` instance as an `ivar` and release it in the `dealloc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `[tView release];`   `TestViewController`'s `dealloc` method will automatically get called. And `Objects` of this class will be `released`. So Probably you have released that button in `dealloc`. That's why your app is crashing.

This is not the right way to do it. 
You should create a custom view and add that view to `self.view` instead of adding `viewcontroller`'s `view`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you had declared *TestViewController* instance as **local**. So, that only it is getting crash while accessing the controls which are there in the instance.

Declare *TestViewController* instance in **class level(ivar)** and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the target of your button is tView. [tView dealloc] is called after [tView release] as its retainCount decrease to 0.
You should declare tView as a private member variable, such as _tView, and call [_tView release] in your view  controller's dealloc function.

```
@interface **
{
    TestViewController *_tView;
}

if(!_tView){
    _tView=[[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
}
_tView.view.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10,tView.view.frame.size.width , _tView.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:_tView.view];
```

In iOS 5.*, custom container view controllers is supported. (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html )
You can write code like this:

```
TestViewController *tView=[[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
tView.view.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10,tView.view.frame.size.width , tView.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:tView.view];
[self addChildViewController:tView];
[tView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[tView release];
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(aMethod:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.yourViewController addSubview:button];
```

self.viewController means you have define your viewcontroller in .h file and then use you instance of the view controller to add your button.

then you can release your viewController [ViewController Release];

Comment: You can addSubview only for UIView. UIViewController hasn't this method.    [self.yourViewController addSubview:button]; And why then can release viewController?

Comment: [yourViewController.view addSubview:button]; is correct syntex.